# android add badge to navigation draw icon

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

How do I add a notification badge to the icon of a navigation drawer item in Android? All the tutorials I've found show you how to add the notification to the "action view" which means the badges appear to the far-right of the menu text. This is the code I have so far:

```
private void badgeDrawableTest(int menuItemResourceId, int count)
{
     //Create a custom view for the badge.
    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.nav_badge, null);
    TextView badgeView = layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
    badgeView.setText(String.valueOf(count));

    // Get the menu.
    Menu menu = _navigation.getMenu(); //this is null

    //Add the badge view to the menu item layout.
    MenuItem menu_item = menu.findItem(menuItemResourceId);
    if(count < 1)
    {
        menu_item.setActionView(null);
        return;
    }


    menu_item.setActionView(layout);

}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

But this is what I want it to look like

[image]

Comment: Not that much sure but it can be achieved via Layer-list and LayerDrawable. https://medium.com/@akashjha/multiimageview-with-layerlist-ebb16a0850af

Comment: @Akashkumar ...how do I implement this against a MenuItem?

Comment: Hi @Laridpleng, either with   custom layout or use  libraries. app:actionLayout="@layout/custom_layout" in your menu item

Comment: @Akashkumar if you think you have a solution please post it up as an answer for me